# Overload button function in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a usecase where while browsing a website in some of webpage there is a button. I want to overload the function to actually run my local python script instead of going with href link(pointing to some page on server)

I have three solution -

1. Repeated polling to check if button is clicked or not. Whenever it get's clicked I will call the required function. This is certainly not a good idea as it will reduce browser speed.
2. Overriding the button function in source code.
3. Creating a new button for all pages which will call the function only if the actual button is also present in page (otherwise we will show that 'This action can't be performed for this page')

I think 2 and 3 would be better if they could be done but I couldn't get much resources on google. Any link/answer on how can this be done would be of great help.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to run the script on the machine that's running the browser, or on the Web server? And what does Selenium have to do with it?

Comment: Yes the script is on machine and I am getting webpage from server. Selenium is used for automating this task (I have to read some JavaScript variables so I used it)

Comment: @Harry Cutts I have edited the question. And the script that I want to run when that button is clicked requires scraping so I used selenium for the purpose. Can you please look it and let me know if something is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 2 can be done by using chrome/firefox extension. It is not possible to do it with Selenium because it requires editing DOM. 
This [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is probably to run a Python Web server on the local machine, which runs your Selenium code when it receives a particular HTTP request. You could write your server like this using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), for example:

```
from flask import Flask, abort

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/dosomestuff', methods=['POST'])
def display():
    # Check that the request is coming from t
    if request.remote_addr != '127.0.0.1':
        abort(403)

    do_some_stuff()  # Call whatever code you want to run here

    return "Done"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

(Using Flask is probably overkill here, and you could probably do it without a library, but Flask is the method I'm most familiar with.)

Then on your Web page you'd just set up a button to send the appropriate request:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/dosomestuff" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Do some stuff">
</form>
```

Then, so long as your local server is running at the time, clicking the button should trigger your Python code.

Comment: My pleasure! Please accept this answer using the check mark next to it if it answers your question.

Comment: I worked out on the problem more and I have found that my 3rd approach could possibly be implemented if I write a browser extension. I am working on it, if it works then I think the extension is better otherwise I will proceed with your Flask solution and accept it :)